# RESTful API Path design guideline

Tags: php, api, restful-url

I am wondering for a restful API, which of the following would be more practical?

1. myapi.com/users/{userid}
2. myapi.com/users?userid={userid}

I am just confused when we should pass parameter in the URL Param vs. the Path.

Comment: What you have tried how you are making REST call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Params are used to filtering a query:

```
http://www.acme.com/products/?ﬁlter=cats&sort=des
```

And path are used to get an element:

```
http://www.acme.com/products/1234
```

So, I recommend you to use `myapi.com/users/{userid}`.

Jump to slide 60 from [this great presentation](http://slideshare.net/Wombert/designing-http-interfaces-and-restful-web-services-confoo11-20110310) (that I recommend you to read).

Comment: [Another great presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WXYw4J4QOU) and the [slides from it](http://www.slideshare.net/stormpath/rest-jsonapis?from_search=5)